# Gpaste daemon very high cpu pasting images untill killed

Tags: libreoffice, gnome-shell, cpu-load, paste

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS fully up to date, shell 3.36.8, window manager X11, 4 core - 8 thread intel cpu.

I am taking png screenshots with Flameshot 0.6.0, that I then paste in a LibreOffice 6.4.6.2 Writer document, which is long, it is project I am writing.

Some of the images, I convert them first with `$ convert file.png file.jpg` to make them smaller.

Sometimes when pasting the images in LO Writer, or when moving or resizing the images in the LO Writer document, the **Gpaste daemon goes up to 65%-99% cpu** and stays there, until I kill it with `$ kill -9`.

Just did an `$ apt search -f gpaste` and there was one item that was not installed `gpaste-common`, that I also installed.

Could there be optional dependencies or libraries I should be installing or does anyone have some configuration ideas?

Any help would be much appreciated, as this is causing me some trouble with important workflow.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior using KDE Spectacle. I believe it's this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gpaste/+bug/1812523

Answer (score 0):

It seems, for the moment at least, that the problem got solved after installing the aforementioned package `gpaste-common`, which for some odd reason was not installed by default along with the rest of gpaste.

Updating my answer after a few days, the problem is not so prevalent as before installing `gpaste-common`, but is still occurring.